# How to convert normal array into yii object array

Tags: yii

My normal array is like this

**Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => companyadmin
            [type] => 2
            [description] => companyadmin
            [bizrule] => companyadmin
            [data] => N;
            [created_by] => 15
            [trade_company_id] => 0
        )

)
**

and i want to convert it to yii object array. hows this convertible?

Comment: What is a yii object array?

Comment: sorry i am new in yii.i mean model array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want create model from array

```
CActiveRecord::model('ClassName')->populateRecord($data).
```

or

```
$model = new ClassModel;
$model->attributes = $data;
```

Comment: Thanx @Konstantin. but in rights module i cant use this.

Comment: Try to describe in detail what you have  and what you want to do

Comment: Address::model()->findAll() gives me array.i used 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM authitem WHERE created_by=".Yii::app()->user->id;
                            $dbCommand = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
                            $data = $dbCommand->queryAll(); but array format is different. so i want same array format like other model.

Comment: Method CActiveRecord.findAll() use populateRecords too:
retrun $this->populateRecords($command->queryAll(), true, $criteria->index)